# d3 zooming charts together in different divs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I have multiple charts in different divs on the same page. All charts
have zoom/pan implemented. However, I want to implement synchronized zooming/panning across all charts, such that when someone zooms/pans one chart all charts zoom/pan together. 
In other words, I'd like to implement mbostock's Focus and Context (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367) when they are in different divs. 
I'm using angular.